# Mostrar todos los usuarios online en Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, session, redis

Estoy queriendo mostrar todos los usuarios actualmente conectados y se me ocurrió la siguiente manera, la cual no sé si es la correcta.

Primero detecto el evento de cuando se loguea el usuario y seteo en redis una variable de session:

```
Redis::set('user:id:' . $event->user->id, json_encode($event->user));
```

entonces luego me queda comparar por cada usuario si existe por ejemplo el usuario 42. Redis::get('user:id:42').

y cuando se desloguea detecto ese evento y elimino a ese usuario

```
 Redis::del('user:id:' . $event->user->id);
```

No se si es lo correcto usando redis o usando database para las sessiones, o hay alguna otra forma de hacer esto.

Comment: Recien estoy empezando con redis y este tema, entonces no sabría responderte, por eso mi gran duda era si usar las sessiones en base de datos o redis, no sabia si redis mantiene solo en el navegador que se crea! @sioesi

Comment: Esta pregunta casi que se basa en opiniones. En todo caso, almacenar las sesiones en Redis es correcto, de hecho es una practica común para aplicaciones escalables.

Comment: Pero como dice sioesi, redis no se almacena en el navegador del usuario solamente? entonces para hacer lo  que yo quiero tendria que almacenar en base de datos las sesiones  @Shaz

Comment: No para nada, creo que no entiendes como funciona Redis, o no entiendo lo que quieres decir.

Comment: solo pregunte como funcionaba, de hecho no se laravel pero me interesa saber esta funcionalidad, me quedo con que @Shaz sabe de lo que habla, elimino mis comentarios

Comment: Estoy empezando con redis por eso tengo unas confusiones. 
Los tutoriales que vi usan database para las sessiones de usuario y pense que usan database porque redis se almacenaba solo en el navegador del usuario. 
La ves correcta a la solución que propuse arriba? @Shaz

Comment: lograste hacerlo??

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper si pude hacerlo pero en un sistema de una empresa que trabajaba hace unos meses el cual ya no tengo mas ese proyecto

Comment: pero fue posible con redis?

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper si fue posible